# Render looks washed out

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I try and render my chair in Cycles which in Blender looks like this

[image: Chair in Blender]

I get this

[image]

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8KLfrj7pklTK_iQe4ld_WaVp4j6TElB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use Multiply mode of Mix node for ambient occlusion, it's shown in the tutorial by BlenderGuru you're likely doing as well. I believe he explains also to not overdo that

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow some tutorials? Because this happens due to Composition you have setup:

[image]

I am not 100% sure what you wanted to do with that composition but MixRGB set to Mix gave you that washed-out white look
If I change it to Overlay for example:
[image]

Now it looks more like what you wanted to get... So my question is, what did you want to accomplish with that composition? Or did you follow the tutorial?

Oh so you wanted to add Ambient Occlusion, not sure how that works, I have never done it in composition but I think that Mix is not the right way to do it.

Comment: @JoeBlah The answer is correct, it's the compositing which "bleaches" your image. I guess what you (or the tutor) wanted to achieve was darkening the occluded areas with the _Ambient Occlusion_ output... so instead of setting the _MixRGB_ node to _Mix_ you should try _Multiply_ instead. The _Fac_ value then determines how much the original image is darkened (if the _Ambient Occlusion_ is in the second color input as you already have it).

Comment: Thank you so much!